# Couldn't download a Raspbian image

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got this problem while I was trying to download a Raspbian image to my computer? Do you know how can I fix this issue?

```
/tmp/m0I8+EXY.zip.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
```

Comment: Please give us some more information. On what OS with what software under what circumstances does this happen?

Comment: and also from where you downloaded the image

Comment: everything goes well but in one moment after about 200MB it fails with message I`ve sent you. I am using wireless connection to download it.
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ i tried both versions, and only zip file

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this does not happen right away. Possibly an IP address clash or some other networking problem?

Comment: yes after 200MB it crashes. So the problem is my wifi ? What can I check to fix it ?

Comment: Well, like I said make sure your IP address is unique. Also if this was ethernet I would guess a wrong MTU value could also cause such troubles.

Comment: thank You, really :) the problem was that I didnt have enough memory :)